# How do I access my wordpress users' linked in connections?

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

I have a wordpress site that users can register with. How do I access my users' linked in connections? I can have them register their linked in user details or log in via their linked in details if necessary or possible....

Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be available any more - see [this](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes?u=0) post.

There's a tutorial available at [developer.linkedin.com](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#) on enabling authenticated API requests after requesting your users' permission. Even if you enable those requests, you may not be able to request users' connections if LinkedIn removed that capability.